# Why is copy constructor called here?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have the following code:

```
template<class T = char>
class String
{
public:

    // Default constructor
    String()
        : buffer(nullptr),
        len(0)
    {
        cout << "Default constructor" << endl;
    }

    // Constructor
    String(const char* s)
    {
        cout << "Constructor (const char*)" << endl;
        //...
    }

    // Virtual destructor.
    virtual ~String()
    {
        cout << "Destructor" << endl;
        len = 0;
        delete[] buffer;
    }


    // Copy constructor
    String(const String& s)
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
        buffer = new T[s.len];
        std::copy(s.buffer, s.buffer + s.len, buffer);
        len = s.len;
    }


    // Copy assignment operator (uses copy and swap idiom)
    String& operator=(String s)
    {
        cout << "Copy assignment operator (copy and swap idiom)" << endl;
        std::swap(buffer, s.buffer);
        return *this;
    }


    // Move constructor
    String(String&& s)
    {
        cout << "Move constructor" << endl;
    }


    // compound assignment (does not need to be a member,
    // but often is, to modify the private members)
    String& operator+=(const String& rhs)                            
    {                          
        cout << "operator+=" << endl;       
        //...

        return *this; // return the result by reference
    }

    // friends defined inside class body are inline and are hidden from non-ADL lookup
    // passing lhs by value helps optimize chained a + b + c
    // otherwise, both parameters may be const references
    friend String operator+(String lhs, const String& rhs)
    {
        cout << "operator+" << endl;

        lhs += rhs; // reuse compound assignment
        return lhs; // return the result by value (uses move constructor)
    }


private:

    T* buffer;
    size_t len;

};


int main()
{
    String<> s("Hello ");
    String<> s2("World");

    // call copy constructor first?
    String<> s3 = s + s2;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
Constructor (const char*)
Constructor (const char*)
Copy constructor
operator+
operator+=
Move constructor
Destructor
```

My question is why is the copy constructor called immediately in:

```
String<> s3 = s + s2;
```

Comment: 2. Are you asking why a copy isn't elided?

Comment: @juanchopanza The return value (being an rvalue) is actually moved.

Comment: @juanchopanza - lhs will be moved out of the function and into the return value. It's guaranteed.

Comment: But the return value is not an rvalue.

Comment: @juanchopanza - It is an rvalue. It's a `String`.

Comment: @StoryTeller How so? That used to predicated on it being a candidate for copy elision, which it isn't. But maybe that changed since C++11.

Comment: @StoryTeller It is `lhs`. It is called `lhs`. It is most definitely NOT an rvalue.

Comment: @juanchopanza - I never said `lhs` is an rvalue. I said the functions return value is an rvalue. And since `lhs` is a parameter, C++11 [class.copy/32](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.copy#32) mandates the return value to be constructed out of the moved `lhs`.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's the quote I was looking for, thanks. So there's no copy elision, but the move constructor gets selected anyway. I was wrong about the latter part.

Comment: @Nick It isn't moved because it lhs an rvalue (it isn't) but because the standard says so. That usually means it is safe to implement without breaking anything or creating any strange situations. However, note that RVO *is* inhibited, so if you're type isn't efficiently movable, by taking a parameter by value you would be pessimizing for the case where lvalues are passed to the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A *value copy* of `s` is taken by `friend String operator+(String lhs, const String& rhs)`, essentially because `s` is not an anonymous temporary and is therefore not an appropriate candidate for move construction. Taking that value copy requires the copy constructor.

Comment: @StoryTeller But that would require a copy inside the method, right?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the copy constructor is called to receive the return value of the `+` operator.